# MongoDB :: Get 10 records for distinct "Person"

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a large database in `mongodb` which i would like to get 10 `distinct` data documents witch the values of a specific field is not repeated. In other words it is `distinct`. How should I write the code?

```
public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public Person()
    {
        UniqueId = GetUniqueKey(8);
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOD { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string Mother { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvalidatedAt { get; set; }
    public string InvalidatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
}
```

in the person class, unique value is unique for each person, but each time the person gets edited, the old data will not be replaced, we will add a new set of data. this means each person can have multiple records. 
Now I want to get top 10 people where for each one i want only the latest record.

how do I get the latest record of 10 unique keys?

Comment: How do you determine the latest record?  Is there an effective date or version every time you add a person class because of an edit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it in C# but in the mongo shell, I think you could simply do (assuming that `UniqueID` corresponds to `_id`):

```
db.persons.aggregate([
{'$sort': {'_id':-1}}, //Descending sort : we want the latest insertions first
{'$group': //Grouping will remove distinct objects
    {'_id':
        {
            'FirstName':'$FirstName',
            'MiddleName':'$MiddleName',
            'LastName':'$LastName',
            //add more fields to make sure the Person is unique
        }
    }
},
{'$limit':10},
{'$project': //This step is not required but it gives a nicer output
    {
        '_id': 0,
        'FirstName':'$_id.FirstName',
        'MiddleName':'$_id.MiddleName',
        'LastName':'$_id.LastName',
        //and so on for other fields from your $group's _id
    }
}
])
```

Here in the `$group` clause I only put first, middle and last name but *put all fields that make a person unique inside the `_id`* (you know about your data, I don't!).

I'm a beginner myself with MongoDB and I don't have access to Mongo so my syntax might be off a bit.